# Hibernate Session Factory javax/xml/bind/JAXBException error

Tags: java, hibernate

I'm trying to make some kind of simple java + hibernate app. Somehow when i run the app there is an error.

> CreateStudentDemo.java

```
package com.basicproject.hibernate.demo;

import org.hibernate.Session;
import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration;

import com.basicproject.hibernate.demo.entity.Student;
public class CreateStudentDemo {

    public static void main(String[] args) {


        // create session factory
        SessionFactory factory = new Configuration()
                .configure("hibernate.cfg.xml")
                .addAnnotatedClass(Student.class)
                .buildSessionFactory();


        // create session
        Session session = factory.getCurrentSession();

        try {
            // create a student object
            System.out.println("Creating new student object...");
            Student tempStudent = new Student("Luke", "Samson", "ls@bk.com");

            // start a transaction
            session.beginTransaction();

            // save the student object
            System.out.println("Saving the student...");
            session.save(tempStudent);

            // commit transaction
            session.getTransaction().commit();

            System.out.println("Done!");
        }
        finally {
            factory.close();
        }
    }

}
```

> Student.java

```
package com.basicproject.hibernate.demo.entity;

import javax.persistence.Column; import javax.persistence.Entity; import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue; import javax.persistence.GenerationType; import javax.persistence.Id; import javax.persistence.Table;

@Entity @Table(name="student") public class Student {

    @Id     @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)   @Column(name="id")  private int id;

    @Column(name="first_name")  private String firstName;

    @Column(name="last_name")   private String lastName;

    @Column(name="email")   private String email;

    public Student() {

    }

    public Student(String firstName, String lastName, String email) {       this.firstName = firstName;         this.lastName = lastName;       this.email
= email;    }

    public int getId() {        return id;  }

    public void setId(int id) {         this.id = id;   }

    public String getFirstName() {      return firstName;   }

    public void setFirstName(String firstName) {        this.firstName = firstName;     }

    public String getLastName() {       return lastName;    }

    public void setLastName(String lastName) {      this.lastName = lastName;   }

    public String getEmail() {      return email;   }

    public void setEmail(String email) {        this.email = email;     }

    @Override   public String toString() {      return "Student [id=" + id + ", firstName=" + firstName + ", lastName=" + lastName + ", email=" + email + "]";  }

}
```

And the error. It seems like i'm missing something but i can't realise that is it yet.

> Error

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/xml/bind/JAXBException     at org.hibernate.boot.spi.XmlMappingBinderAccess.<init>(XmlMappingBinderAccess.java:43)     at org.hibernate.boot.MetadataSources.<init>(MetadataSources.java:87)   at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.<init>(Configuration.java:123)   at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.<init>(Configuration.java:118)   at com.basicproject.hibernate.demo.CreateStudentDemo.main(CreateStudentDemo.java:14) Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.xml.bind.JAXBException  at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:582)  at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:185)   at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:496)
```

Hopefully it can help resolve my problem. Thank You for help. There is also a lib folder in my project. Contains Hibernate's libs(required) and mysql connector.

Answer (score 3):

**I think you're attending the same online course as me! In previous lessons the instructor posted a solution to this problem :**

This happens because of Java 9 and higher.

Java 9 and higher has removed java.xml.bind from its default classpath. That's why we get the class not found exception.  We have to explicitly add JAR files to the build path.

---

Solution

For Java 9 and higher, you need to additional JAR files.

You need to download the following JAR files:

- javax.activation-1.2.0.jar
- jaxb-api-2.3.0.jar
- jaxb-core-2.3.0.jar
- jaxb-impl-2.3.0.jar

---

1. Download the files using links below:

http://search.maven.org/remotecontent?filepath=com/sun/activation/javax.activation/1.2.0/javax.activation-1.2.0.jar

http://search.maven.org/remotecontent?filepath=javax/xml/bind/jaxb-api/2.3.0/jaxb-api-2.3.0.jar

http://search.maven.org/remotecontent?filepath=com/sun/xml/bind/jaxb-core/2.3.0/jaxb-core-2.3.0.jar

http://search.maven.org/remotecontent?filepath=com/sun/xml/bind/jaxb-impl/2.3.0/jaxb-impl-2.3.0.jar

---

2. Copy the JAR files to the lib folder of your project

- javax.activation-1.2.0.jar
- jaxb-api-2.3.0.jar
- jaxb-core-2.3.0.jar
- jaxb-impl-2.3.0.jar

---

Use the following steps to add the JAR files to your Java Build Path.

3. Right-click your project, select Properties
4. On left-hand side, click Java Build Path
5. In top-center of dialog, click Libraries
6. Click Classpath and then Click Add JARs ...
7. Navigate to the JAR files /lib

Select the files:
javax.activation-1.2.0.jar
jaxb-api-2.3.0.jar
jaxb-core-2.3.0.jar
jaxb-impl-2.3.0.jar

8. Click OK then click Apply and Close

Eclipse will perform a rebuild of your project and it will resolve the related build/runtime errors.

Comment: Thanks @Little Pie - I'm also following the same course.

Answer (score 1):

You miss `jaxb-api-1.0.jar` in your classpath.

if you are maven add the following dependency to your code:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.xml.bind</groupId>
    <artifactId>jaxb-api</artifactId>
    <version>1.0</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: I'm not using maven.

Comment: @BaSic Then download it and add it to your classpath

Comment: New error:
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: javax.xml.bind.JAXBContext.newInstance([Ljava/lang/Class;)Ljavax/xml/bind/JAXBContext;

Comment: @BaSic ok then is is the wron Version. try a newer one

Comment: Error again Exception in thread "main" org.hibernate.internal.util.config.ConfigurationException: Unable to perform unmarshalling at line number 0 and column 0 in RESOURCE hibernate.cfg.xml. Message: null

Comment: i guess your `hibernate.cfg.xml` file is wrong or not found or not set. It is not possible to see in the shared code

Answer (score 1):

Please add the below jar in your project classpath.
http://central.maven.org/maven2/javax/xml/bind/jaxb-api/2.2.11/jaxb-api-2.2.11.jar

Comment: Exception in thread "main" org.hibernate.internal.util.config.ConfigurationException: Unable to perform unmarshalling at line number 0 and column 0 in RESOURCE hibernate.cfg.xml. Message: null

Answer (score 0):

Please change the JRE from the STS/Eclipse to 8 version.
Don't use JRE 1.8 in JDK 16.

Comment: Do you intend this to be an answer according to [answer]? If not please delete it.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -2):

Changed to java 8 instead of java 9 and working perfectly fine.

Comment: Not really a fix, please see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43574426/how-to-resolve-java-lang-noclassdeffounderror-javax-xml-bind-jaxbexception-in-j